# "Import" a sourceforge project into Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, sourceforge

I am new to OSX and Xcode. I got a macbook with Xcode 3.0 and downloaded the C++ of a sourceforge project, which comes with the structure:

```
config.mk
doc
include
lib
Makefile
soruces
```

in this kind of projects I usually work with "vi" and edit the ncesasry files. Here I want to debug the code and use subversion. What is the best way to "import" this source code into Xcode? Should I just only add source files or the entire tree?

TThanks

Answer (score -1):

- Download
- Open folder by clicking on the triangle
- find already ready Xcode icon click on it...